# List layer by data type in python window, eg: Layer == Polyline or Layer == Point

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, linear-referencing

I am trying to locate features along routes for polyline and point features in a map.  The locate features along routes tool requires two separate parameters; one for polyline and one for point features.  I want to include an if, else statement in my script to handle this.  However, I cannot find information that will allow me to identify layers by data type in a map. Once I id layer types in the map, how can I leverage that shapeType into an if else statement?

example:

````
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
Map1 = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
arcpy.env.workspace = #filepath
in_routes = arcpy.GetParametersAsText(0)
for i,lyr in enumerate(Map1.listLayers()):
    if(arcpy.Describe(lyr).datatype)=='FeatureLayer':
         print(arcpy.Describe(lyer).shapeType)

for i,lyr in enumerate(Map1.listLayers()):
    if 'FeatureLayer' == "Polygon":
    arcpy.LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes_lr(lyr, in_routes, "RouteId", "0 Feet", arcpy.env.workspace + "//" + "{}Located{}".format(lyr,i),"MapRotueId Line FMEAS TMEAS", "FIRST", "DISTANCE", "ZERO", "FIELDS", "M_DIRECTION)

    else:
    arcpy.LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes_lr(lyr, in_routes, "RouteId", "10 Feet", arcpy.env.workspace + "//" + "{}Located{}".format(lyr,i),"MapRotueId POINT StationPOINT", "FIRST", "DISTANCE", "ZERO", "FIELDS", "M_DIRECTION)```
````

Comment: You probably need to check for case sensitivity but `lyr` will be a Layer object and not a string which your error message should be saying (always include these in your posts).  It's `type` or `dataType` (I've not checked which) property is what you probably need.

Comment: I rolled this question back to the state where its answer seems to apply because it appeared you were trying to ask a new/morphed question within this one.  Whenever, a question is answered rather than then changing it to a new/morphed question perhaps consider accepting the answer and hitting the Ask Question button to start writing your next question.

Answer (score 1):

```py
for i,lyr in enumerate(map1.listLayers()):
        if(arcpy.Describe(lyr).dataType)=='FeatureLayer':
            print(arcpy.Describe(lyr).shapeType)
            if arcpy.Describe(lyr).shapeType=='Polygon':
                #Do something with polygon
            if arcpy.Describe(lyr).shapeType=='Point':
                #Do something with point
```

Comment: thank you. That helped immensely. I made an edit to the question. How can I accommodate the resulting shapeType into an if, else statement?

Comment: This tool worked fine, running it again with new layers added into the map I get an error saying:  Attribute Error: DescribeData: Method shapeType does not exist,  In the python window print(arcpy.Describe(lyr).shapeType works just fine